# Error while running conf.js file from Eclipse

Tags: protractor

I am starting to use protractor using eclipse, configured everything, nodejs, protractor, webdriver, but while running protractor with eclipse I am facing below issue with protractor.

Can someone please help me.

**Environment details:**

```
C:\Users\User>protractor --version
Version 5.1.1

C:\Users\User>npm --version
3.10.10

C:\Users\User>npm-windows-upgrade
'npm-windows-upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\User>node -v
v6.10.3
```

**Error facing**

```
**C:\Users(user)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cli\logger.js:66
info(...msgs) {
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object. (C:\Users(user)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\we
bdriver-manager\built\lib\cli\index.js:8:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)**
```

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that there is a error in parsing the Javascript of webdriver-manager. webdriver-manager was updated to ES6 (and that's why we need Node 6+) and threw the `...` errors in the past for older version of node.

Based on that I would say that Eclipse is running on an older version. After searching the [webdriver-manager git](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager) I found [this issue](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/192). I think it matches your problem and also gives you the steps to check which version of node Eclipse is using.

Hope it helps

Comment: <3 <3 <3 Thank you so much you saved my week-end