# ECONNREFUSED Webdriver errors in eclipse when running Protractor

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver, protractor

So, I was following this tutorial on getting my existing protractor files imported to Eclipse as Java project, installing angular/protractor configurations on eclipse and running the files:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dZ3isYcthI

But then I got into the weeds on this error: [Error while running conf.js file from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893756/error-while-running-conf-js-file-from-eclipse)

In attempt to resolve it, following instructions on the youtube tutorial, I replaced the selenium webdriver folder in Eclipse with the selenium webdriver folder in my node modules folder in AppData by dragging and dropping

Now my conf.js file will not run as protractor on Eclipse even though the file will execute successfully from the command line. Error is:

> (node:53640) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir()          instead.
>   [15:11:38] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   [15:11:38] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444   /wd/hub
>   [15:11:39] E/launcher - Error code: 135
>   [15:11:39] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
>   [15:11:39] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444 at ClientRequest. (C:\Workspace\testUltimateQASite\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)

The js line it is pointing to in the index file is the last line of this function:

```
request.on('error', function(e) {
if (e.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
  setTimeout(function() {
    sendRequest(options, onOk, onError, opt_data, opt_proxy);
  }, 15);
} else {
  var message = e.message;
  if (e.code) {
    message = e.code + ' ' + message;
  }
  onError(new Error(message));
  }
  });
```

My conf.js file is as follows:

```
// conf.js
//var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var os = require('os'); os.tmpDir = os.tmpdir;

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['qaSpec.js'],


//module.exports = { 
params: {
  url : 'http://phptravels.com/demo/'
  /* login: {
    url: 'http://phptravels.com/demo/',
    username: 'juliel@ibm.com',
    password: 'password' 

    }*/
 }
 };
```

Comment: please post your node and selenium versions?

Answer (score 2):

The error is basically stating that your Selenium server doesn't seem to be running. Notice how you are seeing a connection refused error.

Please check if you have started the selenium server as described in the official documentation here : http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial#setup

For more information on setting up eclipse and protractor you might want to refer here as well :https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor

Comment: Hm, I felt that it should run within eclipse. I guess they havent built that in from the last link :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your project's architecture by reading post several times and still got a bit confused.

I am not sure how do you manage Webdriver?

For Protractor project I would recommend using proper `NodeJS` project's structure as well as using any JS task runner. `Grunt` might be a good choice. 
There are plenty Webdriver Manager plugins as well as Protractor managers so you will be able to load your project's dependencies and run test with single Grunt command.

**UPDATE**: [this](https://github.com/nikprix/Protractor_Demo) demo project might be useful in understanding the use of Grunt and its dependencies in Angular project's architecture.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking into Grunt and Bower to see what they are and how they can help me. Part of this is me not having a lot of node experience and being confused on dependencies and structure. Several protractor tutorials reference Grunt without explaining it properly and I feel like I took a node.js class at a workshop the other weekend, but it was geared towards developers and not testers and I didn't get much out of it.

Comment: Coming up with rigth project's architecture for Protractor took me some time too and it was not an easy task since I was doing Java+Webdriver all the time. I have one demo project which I will commit on GitHub and share it a bit later, you might find it useful.

Comment: @JuliePixie I updated my answer with demo project, hope it won't confuse you even more.